# Problems uploading an existing site to a secondary site in WordPress Multisite

Tags: wordpress

I need help with a problem I am facing while trying to import an existing site to a secondary site in a WordPress Multisite environment.

I have created a new secondary site in my WordPress Multisite installation and want to transfer an existing site to the new secondary site. I have exported the content from the original site using the WordPress export function and imported the file into the corresponding secondary site.

However, after completing the import process, the secondary site does not display correctly. The appearance and layout does not match the original site, and some functionality seems to be missing. I have checked the theme settings, plugins and internal links, but have not been able to fix the problem.

I would like to know if there are additional steps I need to take to properly import an existing site into a secondary site in a WordPress Multisite environment. Are there specific adjustments I need to make? Do I need to modify file paths and URLs to match the new secondary site?

I would greatly appreciate any advice, suggestions or steps to take to fix this problem and make sure the secondary site displays correctly. thank you very much in advance for your help!

I tried to transfer an existing site to a secondary site in a WordPress Multisite environment using the WordPress export/import function. I exported the content from the original site and imported it into the corresponding secondary site. However, after the import, the secondary site does not display correctly. The appearance and layout does not match the original site, and some functionality seems to be missing. I have checked the theme settings, plugins and internal links, but have not been able to fix the problem.

I expected the secondary site to correctly display the content, appearance and functionalities of the original site after the import. I expected that the theme settings, plugins and internal links would remain intact and that the secondary site would look and function like the original site. However, this has not happened and I am looking for advice and suggestions on how to fix this problem and get the secondary site to display correctly.